# Automating SharePoint Online access for External Users through Flow/Azure

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, azure-functions, azure-automation, power-automate

I'm quite new to SharePoint/Azure/PowerShell, so apologies if what I'm asking is a stupid question!

We currently have client SharePoint sites hosted on our O365 tenant, with access to each site to be rolled out to each of our respective clients shortly. Initially, only the senior management of each client will have access to the sites, however as time goes on it's likely we'll be adding everyone else too; To streamline the new user process and save us from having to add each individual staff member, we've been considering using a Flow to automate user access instead, with the goal of adding authenticated external users without much real input from administrators other than a simple approval/rejection process.

The overall plan is as follows:

Visio Outline<
[image]

1. Each Client site has a SharePoint Custom List, titled "Employee Access List". Said list will have the following columns: Request ID (Text), First Name (Text), Last Name (Text), Job Title (Text), Company (Text), Contact Number (Text), E-Mail (Text), SharePoint Access (Yes/No Boolean).
2. If a member of staff requires access to the SharePoint site, then their respective manager will add the staff member to the list and fill in all the above fields, setting the "SharePoint Access" item value to "Yes".
3. This will trigger the flow and an approval email to be sent to myself and another administrator, with said email detailing the user to be created, and who has submitted the request.
4. **Script insertion somehow - This would then run if the request was approved, and set the user up with access.**
5. Email notification is automatically then sent to the creator of SharePoint list item, notifying them that the user now has access.

Step 4 is where I'm a little stuck in regards to what to do if the request is approved - I've written a little PowerShell script below which nearly achieves what I'm going for, in that it creates an external user PnP Group and PnP Role Definition (If there isn't one already), pulls what's in the "E-mail" fields on the "Employee Access" list and runs Add-PnPUsertoGroup to pull the users to the PnP group, which then sends the users an email with a link to the SharePoint site, allowing them to access it. However:

- The script I've written targets everyone on the SharePoint List, whereas ideally I would just want the script to target the sole user that's been newly added to the list/is listed in the approval email, and only them. I'm assuming that I'd have to pipe information from the Flow into a script, which I'm not even sure is possible, and if it is, I haven't got a clue how to do it.
- I know that that Azure Functions and Azure Automation can be used to insert scripts into Flows, but I don't have experience of either so I'm not sure which is the more suitable option. Is there any guidance on how to insert PowerShell scripts with them, and how to pipe what's in a flow into said scripts?

PowerShell Script as follows:

[image]

Hope this all makes sense - Any guidance would be appreciated.

Thank you!

EDIT:
Just as a bit of extra information, here is the Flow as it currently is:

[Flow Part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EMh83.png)

[Flow Part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0StK.png)

[Flow Part 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7J1f.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have since found an answer to the above - whilst Azure Functions/Automation are an option, you don't necessarily need them or PowerShell scripts running from Flow, in this case my goal scenario was achieved using an MS Graph Invitation API, App Permissions and a HTTP SharePoint call instead.

See attached screenshots:

[Flow Answer 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZPhs.png)

[Flow Answer 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELGZk.png)

[Flow Answer 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLLOv.png)

Step 1: Set up an App with permissions to make calls to MS Graph - use this guide for help on how to do so - http://blogopaxio.azurewebsites.net/accessing-graph-api-from-microsoft-flow-using-application-permissions-2/

Step 2: Add HTTP to MS Graph and set parameters as in screenshot 1 of this post - this action will create guest user and invitation URL the user would need to sign in to the site.

Step 3: At this point, run the flow so that we can get the 'inviteRedeemURL' from the body of the Output for the HTTP step - you will need this particular URL to send separately in your email to the end user.

Step 4: Throw in a pause for a minute or 2 just to make sure that the information from the previous actions 'sticks' - provided it all works, at this point, the user will actually have their guest account created and you'll be able to see them under Users in your O365 admin centre, however they won't be aware of their account access yet (We'll notify them of this in our email at the end).

Step 5: Add the user to SharePoint security group with a "Send HTTP Request to SharePoint" action. Please note that the "sitegroups(19)" in the URI of this action refers to the ID number of the PnP group you're putting them in, so in my case the group ID was 19. If you're unsure of the ID of your group, connect to your SharePoint Site through PowerShell with PnP commands, then run Get-PnPGroup.

Step 6: Send the email to the invited user with the Outlook Send Email action - FYI -the "SharePoint Site" variable in my screenshot is actually the "inviteRedeemURL".

Hope this helps anyone else that's unsure of how to do this. If anyone has a better solution that achieves this by all means post it!

Thanks!